# google-voice not working outside of gnome

Tags: ubuntu, voip, google-talk, xmonad

I got google-voice working in ubuntu under Gnome. But for some reason when I log into my WM, Xmonad, google voice doesn't recognize my webcam.

Do I need to run some daemon or app along with my WM to get google-voice to work?

Comment: Have you checked the list of processes when in GNOME vs the list of processes when in xmonad? Run something like `pstree -ac` or `ps -ax` when in GNOME and do the same when in xmonad, then compare the outputs with something like `diff file1 file2`

Comment: That might help diagnose the problem, but Ubuntu loads a bunch of crap and I'd have to google each one to see what's important.

Comment: You should add the `diff` to the question. It might help in solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.  I was struggling with the same problem (I use openbox), then ran across this thread:

[Edited out because superuser won't let me post more links]

You can try downgrading to 3.7:

Temp fix is to roll back to Google Talk v3.7.1.0-1

Ubuntu 64-bit
http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/pool/main/g/google-talkplugin/google-talkplugin_3.7.1.0-1_amd64.deb

Ubuntu 32-bit
http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/pool/main/g/google-talkplugin/google-talkplugin_3.7.1.0-1_i386.deb

Worked like a charm.